# CentOS 6 DHCP server configuration

Tags: dhcp, centos6

I have a CentOS 6 server running on a virtual host. The IP address on this host get assigned through DHCP host and another interface has an static IP ( a test network). I want to setup an private DHCP server on private interface. So that it didn't conflict with existing DHCP server.
How can I achieve using my other interface. The host details are as below

1. Physical Host: Running Esxi 5.5
2. N/W 1: Address assign using DHCP.
3. N/W 2: Private interface using 192.168.42.1

So I want to setup a private DHCP on N/W but need to make sure that it didn't conflict with N/W 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples provided by the isc-dhcp-server package cover exactly this situation. You should be telling dhcpd about each network so it can make appropriate decisions.

For instance:

```
# No service will be given on this subnet, but declaring it helps the 
# DHCP server to understand the network topology.
subnet 10.42.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.248 {
}

# Service these clients
subnet 10.84.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option domain-name "foilage.brazzers.com";
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 10.84.0.254;
  option ntp-servers 10.84.0.10, 10.84.0.11;

  pool {
    range 10.84.0.100 10.84.0.199;
  }
}
```